# ExceptionInInitializerError when mocking Kotlin suspend function using mockito-kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, mockito-kotlin

I'm writing a Kotlin unit test in Android (/test) and I am getting an error when mocking a suspend function

I'm using     `testImplementation "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0"`

And have some code:

```
@Test fun MyTest() = runBlocking {
  val foo: Foo = mock {
    onBlocking { bar() } doReturn testResponse
  }
  ...
}
```

I've also tried the traditional `whenever(foo.bar()).thenReturn(testResponse)` but I get the same error

When I run the test I get this exception:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.mydomain.myapp.ui.MainViewModelTest$foo$1.invokeSuspend(MainViewModelTest.kt:18)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:272)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:79)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:54)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:36)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
at com.mydomain.myapp.ui.MainViewModelTest.foo(MainViewModelTest.kt:15)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
```

Comment: Have you tried the @Mock annotation on Foo? Or can you give us the whole test class?